# Some nav buttons working, others not

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs4

the buttons within my submenue movie clip don't work. the one's not within a submenu work fine.
my code validates and i'm not getting any errors
any idea on what else i should be checking?

```
///this one doesn't work////    
aboutSub.bio.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, goBio);
function goBio(evtObj:MouseEvent) {
    gotoAndStop("bio");
}


/// this one works////    
home.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, gohome);
function gohome(evtObj:MouseEvent) {
    gotoAndStop("home");
}
```

Comment: What is your question? Please be more specific.

Comment: Please make your code more legible by putting clicking the 101010 button... also indent.

Answer (score 0):

for testing purposes try adding an event listener to the aboutSub MovieClip and see if that works. If it doesn't then check that you don't have another DisplayObject above it and make sure that you have not set anything like mouseEnabled = false or mouseChildren = false on the aboutSub.

If it does work then check that in aboutSub clip that there are no DisplayObjectsw above the buttons etc (so same principle as the first paragraph)